# event.target in function doesn't give expected result

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, addeventlistener

I decided to make a to-do list in JavaScript duplicating what is shown in a video but the video is already two years, so that may be some of the properties or something else changed and was deprecated, really I don't know.
Here is HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>To-Do list</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="input">
    <button id="btn">Add</button>

    <hr>

    <ul id="todo">

    </ul>
    <ul id="done">

    </ul>
           
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is JavaScript:

```
(function() {
    let input = document.getElementById('input');
    let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    let lists = {
        todo: document.getElementById('todo'),
        done: document.getElementById('done')
    };

    let makeTaskHtml = function(str, onCheck) {
        let el = document.createElement('li');
        let checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        let label = document.createElement('span');

        checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
        checkbox.addEventListener('click', onCheck);
        label.textContent = str;

        el.appendChild(checkbox);
        el.appendChild(label);

        return el;
    };


    let addTask = function(list, task) {
        list.appendChild(task);
    };

    let onCheck = function(event) {
        let task = event.target;

        console.log(task);
    };

    addTask(lists.todo, makeTaskHtml('Test-todo'));
    addTask(lists.done, makeTaskHtml('Test-done'));


}());
```

In the function `onCheck` I tried to `console.log` task which I defined in this function before but nothing happened: neither errors nor result I expected to see
What's the problem? May be it is because of `event.target` or addEventListener?
Help me please to reveal it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You function `makeTaskHtml` takes 2 arguments:

```
function makeTaskHtml(str, onCheck)
```

But you are only calling it with one:

```
addTask(lists.todo, makeTaskHtml('Test-todo'));
```

You need to pass in `onCheck` as the second argument or remove the second argument from the function declaration.